# Why the result of this program is always zero?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple program which receives marks, names and ID's of at most 30 students and prints average of their marks. I was wondering why the result of the program is always zero.
I appreciate if anyone could leave me a hint.
Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    char name[30];
    int mark;
    int ID;

} s[30];

int main() {
    int n, i=0, sum=0;
    float average;
    /* printf("enter the number of students: "); */
    scanf("%d", &n);
    /* printf("enter their information: "); */

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%s,%d,%d",s[i].name,&s[i].mark,&s[i].ID);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         sum+=s[i].mark;
    
    average=sum/(float)n ;
    printf("%.2f", average);
}
```

Comment: You understand that C does not care about your indentation, yes?

Comment: It's almost like making indentation a significant thing is a stupid idea which surely no language would ever use :)

Comment: Anyway, did you try verifying what the individual `s[i].mark` values are?

Comment: could you show , the way you inputted the values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format specifier `%s` says to read a string, and it's doing that … including your commas and subsequent characters. It's "greedy".

Then there's nothing left for the `%d` to absorb, so all the integers remain zero.

I suggest you read a line a time, then parse the lines.

Alternatively, there are some suggestions on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15330047/4386278).

---

When faced with a problem like this, you should attempt to narrow it down by examining the values of variables in your debugger, or even just by using `printf`, like this:

```
    printf("%s|%d|%d\n", s[i].name, s[i].mark, s[i].ID);
```

When I put that in your first loop, and pass the following input to the program:

```
2
A,2,3
B,4,5
```

… [the output is this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c71b38aba5bd012):

```
A,2,3|0|0
B,4,5|0|0
0.00
```

… which clearly shows that the parsing is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this line:

```
scanf("%s,%d,%d",s[i].name,&s[i].mark,&s[i].ID);
```

it will not work as you think. To test it I have amended you program.

```
int main() {
    int n = 10, i=0, sum=0;
    int scanfResult;
    float average;
    /* printf("enter the number of students: "); */
    //scanf("%d", &n);
    /* printf("enter their information: "); */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanfResult = scanf("%s,%d,%d",s[i].name,&s[i].mark,&s[i].ID);
        printf("scanf has scanned %d items\n", scanfResult);
        if(scanfResult != 3) 
        {
            printf("you need to find another way of entering the data\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         sum+=s[i].mark; 
    average=sum/(float)n ;
    printf("%.2f", average);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PredEd

What you need to do? You need to read the whale line with `fgets` and the write the parser which will split this string apart

**ALWAYS CHECK THE RESULT OF SCANF**

Comment: I already said this!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re trying to enter names with spaces in them, like

```
Joe Smith,90,1234
```

then the problem is that the `%s` conversion specifier stops reading at the first whitespace character, so it reads `"Joe"` and leaves `"Smith"` in the input stream, which fouls up the next two reads.  Alternately, if you don’t have any spaces, `%s` reads the entire input line into `name` (whether it fits or not, potentially leading to a buffer overflow).

You should use the `%[` conversion specifier instead of `%s` and explicitly size it to avoid risking a buffer overflow.  You should also check the return value of `scanf` to make sure you read all 3 items correctly:

```
/**
 * loop until we have three good inputs;
 * %29[^,] reads up to 29 characters or to the next comma;
 * An array of size 30 can store a string of up to
 * 29 characters plus the string terminator;
 * Added leading blank in the format string to consume
 * any leading whitespace. 
 */
while ( scanf( " 29%[^,],%d,%d", s[i].name, &s[i].mark, &s[i].ID) != 3 )
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Bad input, try again\n" );
   /**
    * clear out the input stream before trying again
    */
   while ( getchar() != '\n' )
     ; // empty loop body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `,` in the `scanf("%s,%d,%d",s[i].name,&s[i].mark,&s[i].ID);`

I changed the code as follow:

```
scanf("%s%d%d",s[i].name,&s[i].mark,&s[i].ID);
```

then input and output were as:
INPUT:

```
2
moh 1 2
test 2 3
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.50
```